# How do I create multiple 1:1 foreign key relationships in Entity Framework 6 Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, one-to-one

Let's pretend I have three tables, each with a primary key called `Id`:

```
TableA
------
Id

TableB
------
Id

TableC
-----
Id
```

The intent is for each of these entities to have a one-to-one navigation property with each other so that I may navigate in any direction given any of the entities. Unfortunately, I have not found a combination of `[Key]`, `[ForeignKey]`, and navigation properties that allows this *more than once per entity.*

For example, this works (Entity Framework thinks `TableA` is the principal in the 1:1 relationship):

```
public class TableA
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; }
    public virtual TableC TableB { get; set; }
}

public class TableB
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("TableA")]
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }
}
```

but this doesn't work:

```
public class TableB
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("TableA,TableC")] // The constructor documentation says this will work, but at runtime it throws an exception
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }

    public virtual TableC TableC { get; set; }
}
```

nor does this:

```
public class TableB
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual TableC TableC { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use attributes to allow these relationships? Currently, if I want to navigate to `TableC` from `TableB`, I must navigate through `TableA`, causing an extra unnecessary database lookup. It seems Entity Framework wants to force a hierarchical relationship where there may be none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a model like this:

```
public class TableA
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; }
    public virtual TableC TableC { get; set; }
}
public class TableB
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("TableA")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }

    public virtual TableC TableC { get; set; }
}

public class TableC
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("TableB")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }
}
```

You don't need to specify a FK property for `TableC` navigation property in the `TableB` entity because `TableB` is principal in the relationship between B and C.

### Update

Try removing the `Required` data annotation and configuring the relationship this way, overriding the `OnModelCreating` method on your context:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TableA>().HasOptional(a => a.TableC).WithOptionalPrincipal(c => c.TableA);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, due to a bug with `[Required]` on navigation properties (https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1571), I am unable to use your solution; however, I suspect it will work since `[Required]` establishes the principal of the relationship. That's why in my example I was stuck using `[ForeignKey]`. Until Microsoft incorporates the pull request, it looks like I'm stuck with the extra traversal. I'll mark you answer as accepted, though, since without the bug I suspect it would work.

Comment: Hello @NathanAldenSr, I can't see what is exception that is throwing to you, but anyway, I update my answer with another possible solution, hope this help you now

Comment: To summarize the bug: Attempting to save an entity that was loaded from the database but didn't have all its `[Required]` navigation properties inspected will throw an exception that the navigation properties are required. It's because navigation properties are lazy-loaded, so without hitting the property's get accessor, the `[Required]` annotiation thinks the value is `null`.

Comment: Did you try with the configuration that I shared in my update?, that lets you configure both end of the relationship as optionals

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks. I usually try to avoid overriding `OnModelCreating` in favor of attributes, but I may have no choice in this case. :)